# special html characters are not rendered correctly in the browser

Tags: html, xhtml, browser, asp.net-mvc-2, htmlspecialchars

I am storing pieces of XHTML as text on a search index.  Once the user submits a search request, I insert this text in my page and return it to the server.  This all works fine except when there is a [ISO 8859-1 Symbol](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) in the text (such as a copyright symbol ©).  The symbol is not represented correctly in the browser, it is displayed as the entity number (&#169; for the copyright symbol ©) and is not displayed as the symbol.

If I copy and paste the XHTML into a static web page and look at it in the browser, the symbol is rendered correctly.

When I do view source, I see the same text string under both conditions mentioned above.

Can you please tell me what is going on, and how do I fix it.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 and using the following code to add the XHTML inside an .ascx page where my Model is a collection o strings, each holding a piece of XHTML:

```
<%foreach(string s in ViewData.Model)  {%>
  <%= s %>
  <%} %>   
<%
```

Thanks for your help!

CoderGeek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to html encode the strings in order to render them correctly:

```
<%= Html.Encode(s) %>
```

or if you are using ASP.NET 4 you may take advantage of the new [code nugget](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx) shortcut:

```
<%: s %>
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I am trying to do.  I want to render html, not render the text representation of html. My html renders fine except for these special characters.

Answer (score 0):

you need to html encode your input though so that copyrigth symbol is acually © or ©
this will then output back out as html encoded or you can html decode !!!! to return it back to the original state

Comment: lol shoould be & # 1 6 9 ; (as one string but what do ya know its html encoded lol

Comment: Thanks!
To get the browser to display &amp;#169; instead of &#169; type the following without the space:

& amp;#169;

There is no input to html encode.  All of this comes from my server.  And all displays correctly, (the xhtml is rendered properly --  ie, the html elements are rendered), except for the symbols.

Thanks!